# Can't redirect DNS queries to TOR proxy

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, iptables, tor

I've set up a TOR proxy but I can't access to the `.onion` sites. I do surf through the TOR net though.

I set up a PPTP VPN (I know it's insecure but it's just a test) to create a quick IP address swap so I get a `192.168.1.{50 - 60}` IP which I will route through the TOR net.

**Server:** *Debian 7.6*

**Client:** *Windows 7*

This is my `torrc` conf:

```
DNSPort 192.168.1.250:5300
TransPort 192.168.1.250:8118
VirtualAddrNetworkIPv4 10.192.0.0/11
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
AutomapHostsSuffixes .exit,.onion
```

This is my `iptables` conf:

```
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             source IP range 192.168.1.50-192.168.1.60 udp dpt:domain to:192.168.1.250:5300
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             source IP range 192.168.1.50-192.168.1.60 tcp dpts:tcpmux:65535 to:192.168.1.250:8118
```

`netstat -untap` output:

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.250:8118      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16027/tor
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16027/tor
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.250:59864     X.X.X.X:443        ESTABLISHED 16027/tor
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.250:48069     X.X.X.X:9001     ESTABLISHED 16027/tor
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.250:39310     X.X.X.X:8443         ESTABLISHED 16027/tor
udp        0      0 192.168.1.250:5300      0.0.0.0:*                           16027/tor
```

**PPTP router conf:**

[image: DD-WRT PPTP Configuration]

This is what happens when I try to query a `.onion` website:

```
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
11:59:40.870407 IP 192.168.1.50.57575 > 8.8.8.8.53: 36750+ A? google.com. (28)
11:59:41.105780 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 192.168.1.50.57575: 36750 1/0/0 A 74.125.232.233
```

****UPDATE**:**
If I **DO NOT** use the PPTP VPN everything work as expected.

I do not understand why `192.168.1.50` still queries `8.8.8.8:53` when there's the according `iptables` rules which prohibits it and, furthermore, redirects the packet it to the TOR port.

**UPDATE 2, firewall:**

```
    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 524K packets, 123M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.2.3.1             multiport dports 58050,58051,9091,80,22,139,445,5900,5901,5222,8200

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 56226 packets, 8404K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       10.2.3.0/24          10.2.2.0/24
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       10.2.3.0/24          10.2.1.0/24

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 631K packets, 511M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain LOG_AND_DROP (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hmm. I would suggest you review a [sample firewall configuration](http://serverfault.com/a/434010/126632) before you go too much further.

Comment: Why? What's wrong?

Comment: I can't tell why your DNS redirection isn't working, but I can tell that you have a variety of ways for information to leak to the clearnet because your firewall isn't sufficiently closed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your note. How would they leak? (I'm not being picky, I just want to learn)

Comment: Your firewall plainly permits everyone to access the clearnet.

Comment: How can I test whether there are leaks?